# Unable to make a sequential service (HTTP) calls in Angular 5 by using Joins

Tags: angular5

I had a Array with N number of objects. I want to make a service call sequentially. One response comes based on that i will make a another request. Please provide a better approach to handle this scenario through JOINS in Angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switchMap` for this.

```
nestedCalls(user: any) {
    return this.http.get('YOUR_URL').pipe(
      switchMap(data => {

        const body = {
          // do your work woth data - first service object
        };

        return this.http.post('YOUR_URL', body);
      })
    )
  }
```

Or you can do something like below also :

```
       this.service.getData(id, (response) => {
                this.service.getInitiatedEntity(response.id).subscribe(
                    (retData) => {
                      // response - 1st service data
                      // retData - 2nd service data
                    }
                );
        });
```

Hope this help.

Comment: nestedCalls(user: any) {
    return this.http.get('YOUR_URL').pipe(
      switchMap(data => {

        const body = {
          // do your work woth data - first service object
        };

        return this.http.post('YOUR_URL', body);
      })
    )
  }  This is for two service which you written. let suppose i had n number of objects in my array. i want to make a service call one after another sequentially. Once one response then only i will make another api call. Could please let me know i have any ideas regarding this.